# ASCMD for SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-datatools, ascmd

Till now, I used ascmd to execute some queries to SSAS 2008R2. My company begin to install some new SSAS 2012 servers and I want to re-use all my maintenance scripts with these new servers. I can't find any ascmd tool in SQL Server 2012 neither any documents or relatives on the internet.

Does anyone have some information about that? Or a link to download the tool?

When I try to execute a query with my version, i get the following message:

"Microsoft (R) Analysis Services 2008 Command Line Tool
Version 10.0.87.5 X86
Copyright (C) 2008 Microsoft Corporation.  All Rights Reserved.
Ascmd: Exception trying to impersonate user: Could not load file o
crosoft.AnalysisServices, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, Publi
5dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find t
ied.
Ascmd: Execution failed: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsof
ices, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd80
 of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

When I check in C:\Windows\Assembly, I can see that I have the 11.0.0.0 version.

How can I deal with it? I can't use PowerShell script...

Thanks!

Comment: Is that really the actual exact error message text, including all of the partial and missing words in the middle?  Or was that just a cut and paste problem?

Comment: Why can't you use PowerShell? The tool appears to have been migrated to a [cmdlet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh479579.aspx) and PowerShell is usually installed and available on all recent Microsoft OSes.

Comment: @RBarryYoung>c&p problem, this it the correct one:"Microsoft (R) Analysis Services 2008 Command Line Tool
Version 10.0.87.5 X86
Ascmd: Exception trying to impersonate user: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
Ascmd: Execution failed: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServ
ices, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one
 of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: @Pondlife> I can't use powershell for many reasons. One of them is that means to re-write a lot of scripts in another language that we (in the company) does not know at all (not acceptable for my boss). The second important is that the script i'm working on must run on several version (2005-2008-2012) so, i think it will be a bad decision to run different version (one without PS, one with PS...) of the script. It will be very bad to maintain... (I'm quite sure that cmdlet in PS are quite different in 2005 and 2012 ^^)

Comment: @Pondlife> I've just tried, right now, with PS and jsut discovered that my company has blocked the PS "UnRestricted policy" mode... And it will not be possible to un-block this... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the 2008 R2 Analysis Management Objects from [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978). That includes the 10.0.0.0 version.

Comment: It works, thanks!
A little disapointed that the tool is not longer supported in its original form..

Answer (score 0):

take the old ascmd solution from microsoft samples, delete the old reference dll and add new one it will solve ur problem